# ffmpeg generate m3u8 from mp4 (Resume option)

Tags: multithreading, video, ffmpeg, m3u8

I have a mp4 file or other file (non mp4 format) and i need generate ts files and m3u8 playlist.

I am using this command and works fine:

> ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment
>   -segment_list out.m3u8 -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts

Now I need to generate many ts simultaneous so i need a "resume option".

Please see the example below:

One thread (first 20 seconds (0-20))

> ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment
>   -segment_list out.m3u8 -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts

Seconds thread (20 seconds to 40 seconds)

> ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 ......

Third thread (40 seconds to 60 seconds)

> ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 ......

I have lots of core processor to do this jobs.

In resume i need generate .ts files and m3u8 fastest way possible

I need help or advises to resolve my problem.

Prove of concept i build a litle script that use -ss and -t option:

```
<?php

 //generate all the commands using -ss and -t <seconds> 
 $startTime = new DateTime("00:00:00");
 for ($i=1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $data = $startTime->format('H:i:s');
    $exec = 'ffmpeg  -i "<FILE>" -ss '.$data.' -t 10 -c:v copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_start_number '.$i.' -segment_list '.sprintf("%04d", $i).'_test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts '.$i.'stream%05d.ts';
    shell_exec($exec);
    $startTime->modify('+10 seconds');
    echo "\n";
}

//cycle all m3u8 and creates a master hls playlist
$files = glob('*.{m3u8}', GLOB_BRACE);
sort($files);
$ret = "#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
";
foreach($files as $file) {
    $ret .= shell_exec('sed -n -e 6,7p '. $file);
}
$ret .= "#EXT-X-ENDLIST";

file_put_contents('final.m3u8', $ret);

?>
```

Thanks